# Get Nearest Panorama by Location GMaps Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I'm new here and looking for help. I tried almost everything including nodejs, embedden js and others ..

There is very cool feature of google maps js: It can show the nearest available streetview with given location.

http://bloggerbotu.com/Githadi/nearestimage.html?lat=37.952866&lng=34.151230

Here is an example. I edited it a little. 
When we put our lat and long values even doesn't have street view, it finds the nearest location and shows us an image.

And you could see there is a small textbox on the upper right side of the page that shows the location of available streetviews. I need this value.

But they all in browser side. I tried with nodejs but not succesfful. I can't do that.

You'll see there is some kind of processing of queries and when you click somewhere like mountain or out of road, the process starts and find the nearest available location again. And textbox changes with
   `document.getElementById("koordinat").value = data.location.latLng;`

I don't need images or map markers etc. All I want is, when I give *lat* and *long*, a small php script or node based server script that returns me the nearest streetview-available coordinates.

Thanks